# 400 Error - Bad request

Tags: http, browser, request

I know there are probably countless questions on here about 400 errors and I've had a little look around Internet about them, but I was just wondering if someone could shed a little light on the cause/solution(s) for this error.

We have a situation at work where we have an internal web based system; the laptops my department use can access the system with the standard URL: http://servername/webapp without any issue.
However others are getting error 400.

We have tried both IE and Chrome so it's not browser specific, so I'm wondering if it could be related to browser security/config or something?

Basically what normally causes a 400 error?

Answer (score 0):

check the method you are using when do request your URL

Comment: To avoid down votes on your answer, you'd have to include just a little more information on what the possible causes are for his problem to arise, otherwise, this answer is meaningless.